# How-to disable undo (CTRL-Z) in Greatis Form Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, undo

The title says it all. I'm trying to disabled the undo function when called by the shortcut CTRL-Z in the Form Designer from Greatis Software

There is no documentation on the web site.

For those who used greatis Form Designer, I tried to listen to the key up / down / press of the container on which the design is made with no success. The Form Designer seems to catch those keys and handle them and then discard them. The events I listen to don't fire.

Someone as an idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to tell me why I have a down vote on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greatis Form Designer processes only tab and arrows keys (see RootDesigner.cs file), all other keys are processed within native .Net designer.

Comment: Thanks! It oriented me to find the real reason behind my problem, which wasn't Greatis at all. In fact the problem came from a shortcut defined in the toolbar. The shortcut was still effective event if the menu item wasn't shown in the toolbar (i used infragistics ToolbarManager) ...